# How to add a delay or wait to a print() . (python)

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am currently working on a text-based game and I would like to add a delay in the appearance of a text. The text where I want the delay is the third descendant of an if-else command.

I've tried time.sleep() function but that doesn't seem to work.

```
 if path.lower().strip() == "yes":
                print("Then let your journey begin")
            else:
                print("\nWell,")

                print("You don't have much of a choice do you.") 
                # the text I need to delay ^^^
```

So what I'm hoping to do is add a few seconds of delay to the entrance of the commented text.

Comment: Maybe you can use `time.sleep()`? https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/time.html#time.sleep

Comment: Can you elaborate what exactly is not working with time.sleep(3)?

Comment: For clarification, I've tried using time.sleep(), the function turns grey and says "unresolved reference". I haven't used time.sleep() anywhere else in the code and right now I'm just trying to apply it on that particular text.

Comment: Please provide your code including time.sleep()

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
import time

# ...

if path.lower().strip() == "yes":
    print("Then let your journey begin")
else:
    print("\nWell,")
    time.sleep(3) # parameter used here is in seconds
    print("You don't have much of a choice do you.") 
    # the text I need to delay ^^^
```

---

[time.sleep(secs)](https://docs.python.org/3/library/time.html#time.sleep)

> `secs` - The number of seconds the Python program should pause execution. This argument should be either an int or a float.
>
> Suspend execution of the calling thread for the given number of seconds. The argument may be a floating point number to indicate a more precise sleep time. The actual suspension time may be less than that requested because any caught signal will terminate the sleep() following execution of that signal’s catching routine. Also, the suspension time may be longer than requested by an arbitrary amount because of the scheduling of other activity in the system.
>
> Changed in version 3.5: The function now sleeps at least secs even if the sleep is interrupted by a signal, except if the signal handler raises an exception (see [PEP 475](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0475/) for the rationale).

Comment: Thank you so much for your help, I did not know that import time had to be used to use time.sleep(). I appreciate your help, thank you very much.

Comment: @MrZooSuit No problem mate, we've all been there.